# How best to pivot wider only selected rows

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

Below is the sample data

```
  indcode <- c(71,72,81,82,99,000000,71,72,81,82,99,000000)
  year <- c(2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021)
  employment <- c(3,5,7,9,2,26,4,6,8,10,3,31)


  test <- data.frame(indcode, year, employment)
```

The task is to create a new column that would the 000000 value for each year. I know that this involves a pivot wider but how to get the 000000 to repeat is my struggle. Below is the desired result. Hoping to not have 000000 (Total, all industries) be a row. It would be essentially be a duplicate.

```
   Year       indcode    employment     total
   2020         71            3           26
   2020         72            5           26
   2020         81            7           26
   2020         82            9           26
   2020         99            2           26
   2021         71            4           31
           and so on...
```

Comment: Do you want `library(dplyr);library(stringr); test %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(total = employment[str_detect(indcode, '^0+$')]) %>% ungroup %>% filter(str_detect(indcode, "^0+$", negate = TRUE))`

Comment: @akrun, Yes precisely.

Comment: @akrun. Also, where did you learn to do this item     '^0+$'

Comment: It is a regex pattern to match one or more 0s (`+` - means one or more) from the start (`^`) to the end (`$`) of the string.  I used this because you mentioned 00000 etc instead of just 0

Comment: You can check some regex tutorials which would give the info about the metacharacters (`^`, `$`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this by detecting one or more zeros (`+`) from the start (`^`) to the end (`$`) of the string in 'indcode' to subset the 'employment' for each 'year' (grouped) to create a new column and then `filter` out the 0 rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
test %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(total = employment[str_detect(indcode, '^0+$')]) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  filter(str_detect(indcode, "^0+$", negate = TRUE))
```